# Memory Leak with swiftUI List and Firebase database observing childAdded

Tags: list, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, memory-leaks

I'm writing a chat application using firebase , I notice memory leak in ChatView while observing database changes which is when a message is sent or received.

when I comment out the database observation the memory leak dose not happen anymore so I'm guessing this is a firebase problem .

I'm sharing the code so please if you know what is acutely causing the memory leak help me out.

ChatViewModel:

```
class ChatViewModel : ObservableObject  {

/// - sub ViewModels :
@Published private(set) var messages : [MessageModel] = []
private(set) var conversationID : String? = nil

/// set shared conversationID
/// - Parameter convesationID: shared conversationID if exist
func setConverationID(convesationID : String?){
    guard let convesationID = convesationID else {
        print("CONVERSATION ID DOUS NOT EXIT")
        return
    }
    self.conversationID = convesationID
    startObservingConversation()
}
/// start observing the conversation with viewModel conversationID
private func startObservingConversation(){
    guard let conversationID = self.conversationID else {
        return
    }
    DatabaseManager.shared.observeMessagesForConversation(conversationId: conversationID) { [weak self] message in
        self?.messages += message
    }
}}
```

ChatView :

```
struct ChatView: View {

@StateObject var viewModel = ChatViewModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment :  .leading , spacing: 0){
        
        ScrollViewReader { scrollViewReader in
            List{
                ForEach(viewModel.messages) { item in
                    MessageView(messsage: item.text)
                        .id(item.id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

observerMessages :

```
func observeMessagesForConversation(conversationId id :String,compelition : @escaping ([MessageModel]) -> Void ) {
    database.child(id).child("messages").observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
            compelition([])
            return
        }
        var messages : [MessageModel] = []
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard
            let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:value),
            let message = try? decoder.decode(MessageModel.self, from: jsonData) else {
            compelition([])
            return
        }
        messages.append(message)
        compelition(messages)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem here, can you try adding some logs in the observed completion handler? Maybe you have some .onChange of messages, update the database and so it gets in some sort of looping.

Comment: in ChatView I have a .onChange(of: viewModel.messages){} which scroll the list to the last added message .

Comment: Do you modify anywhere else `viewModel.messages`? Also when modifying a `@Published` variable it's better to do it in the main thread `DispatchQueue.main.async { // do the update }`

Comment: No it is a private(set) variable so no class can modify it . Only ViewModel can.

Comment: Yes I meant within the same ViewModel if you had any other method that modified it and was called from somewhere else. This is weird if you say so. Can you post the error from which you inferred the memory leak was caused by the observer